# Return lengths of strings in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to return the length of strings in a range in Google Sheets.

Here's the test cells:

[image]

I have a custom function that should return the length of each string:

```html
function returnLength(array) {
  var returnList = [];
  array.forEach(function(a) {
    returnList.push(a.length);
  });
  return returnList;
}
```

When I use this function in B1, it returns 1 for the length of any of them:

[image]

The thing throwing me off is if I leave off the ".length" in the push to resultArray, it returns the correct strings...

```html
function returnLength(array) {
  var returnList = [];
  array.forEach(function(a) {
    returnList.push(a);
  });
  return returnList;
}
```

[image]

**I know I could use LEN() to handle this example, but this is just a tiny part in a really large project where I need to be able to get the length within the code.**

Comment: *Kind of weird that pushing "a" alone would only add the element itself* No. It still pushed a 1D array. A 2D array is returned would be rendered as shown in your pic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is that `array` is 2 dimensional array like `[["This"],["Is"],["A"],["Test"],["Hello"],["World"]]`. In the case of `returnList.push(a.length);`, the length of the array which is the element of the 2 dimensional array is returned. By this, all values are `1`. So how about this modification?

#### From:

```
returnList.push(a.length);
```

#### To:

```
returnList.push(a[0].length);
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I didn't realize it would be a 2 dimensional array since it was just a single column. Kind of weird that pushing "a" alone would only add the element itself.